# Identify all objects of given class for further processing

Tags: r

Assume you are working with a large working environment and you aren't great about keeping up with your environment variables, or you have some process that generates a lot objects automatically. Is there a way to scan your `ls()` to identify all objects that have a given class? Consider the following simple example:

```
#Random objects in my environment
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100)
z <- rnorm(100)

#I estimate some linear models for fun.
lm1 <- lm(y ~ x)
lm2 <- lm(y ~ z)
lm3 <- lm(y ~ x + z)

#Is there a programmatic way to identify all objects in my environment 
#that are of the "lm" class? Or really, any arbitrary class?
outList <- list(lm1, lm2, lm3)

#I want to look at a bunch of plots for all the lm objects in my environment.
lapply(outList, plot)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the `class` function:

```
Models <- Filter( function(x) 'lm' %in% class( get(x) ), ls() )
lapply( Models, function(x) plot( get(x) ) )
```

(Modified slightly to handle situations where objects can have multiple classes, as pointed out by @Gabor in the comments).

***Update***. For completeness, here is a refinement suggested by @Gabor's comment below. Sometimes we may want to only get objects that are of class X but *not* class Y. Or perhaps some other combination. For this one could write a `ClassFilter()` function that contains all of the class filterling logic, such as:

```
ClassFilter <- function(x) inherits(get(x), 'lm' ) & !inherits(get(x), 'glm' )
```

Then you get the objects that you want:

```
Objs <- Filter( ClassFilter, ls() )
```

Now you can process the `Objs` whatever way you want.

Comment: Thanks @Prasad! It was the `Filter` part of that I wasn't aware of previously. That's pretty slick.

Comment: Thanks, I just discovered `Filter` while looking at `?Reduce`, and it's nice because you don't need to first do `objs <- ls()`, and then extract the ones whose class is `lm`.

Comment: Note that the above assumes that all objects have a single class but some objects may have a vector of classes such as `"glm"` objects which have the class vector: `c("glm", "lm")`, i.e.`"glm"` objects are also `"lm"` objects.  If you had such an object in your workspace the above would give an error.  In addition, depending on whether you wanted to include or exclude `"glm"` objects the answer would be slightly different.

Comment: Good point, I changed the code slightly to test for membership rather than equality, which should handle your first comment. Further refinements should be easy to do from this.

Comment: `inherits(get(x), "lm")` might be more generally applied than searching through the class of objects?

Comment: @Prasad. To be complete I think you need to address both situations: the situation where `"lm`" is an element of the class vector and the situation where `"lm"` is the only class in the class vector.  We don't know which one the poster wants but he may very well only want objects which are `"lm"` objects that are not `"glm"` objects.

Comment: @Gabor - that is a good point, and I can imagine there are lots of other objects in the R-world that contain multiple `class`es, though I'm not that familiar with them. It seems we should be able to add other logical conditions into the anonymous function to suit our needs, right? Maybe something like: `function(x) 'lm' %in% class( get(x) ) & 'glm' %in% class( get(x) ) == FALSE`? I imagine there may be a more efficient way to say "not in", but I'm not familiar with that construct in R.

Comment: @Gavin, yes I like `inherits` better, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Filter` with `inherits` and `ls` in `mget` to get a named `list` of in this case of `lm` objects.

```
L <- Filter(\(x) inherits(x, "lm"), mget(ls()))
#L <- Filter(\(x) inherits(x, "lm") & !inherits(x, "glm"), mget(ls())) #In case glm need to be excluded

identical(unname(L), outList)
#[1] TRUE

lapply(L, plot)
```