# Use ls() or objects() to get objects of class data.frame

Tags: r

Is there anyway I can loop through some set of objects and apply a function to each?

When I type `ls()` or `objects()`, it returns a list of object names. I could like to iterate through this list, identify those which are `data.frame`, and then run a function against each object.

How do I pass an entry from `ls` or `objects` through a function?

Comment: I asked an almost identical question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158830/identify-all-objects-of-given-class-for-further-processing). The answers there have worked swimmingly well for me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The answer given by @jverzani about figuring out which objects are data frames is good. So let's start with that. But we want to select only the items that are data.frames. So we could do that this way:

```
#test data
df <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=11:20)
df2 <- data.frame(a=2:4, b=4:6)
notDf <- 1

dfs <- ls()[sapply(mget(ls(), .GlobalEnv), is.data.frame)]
```

the **names** of the data frames are now strings in the dfs object so you can pass them to other functions like so:

```
sapply( dfs, function(x)  str( get( x ) ) )
```

I used the `get()` command to actually get the object by name (see the [R FAQ](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-turn-a-string-into-a-variable_003f) for more about that)

I've answered your qeustion above, but I have a suspicion that if you would organize your data frames into list items your code would be MUCH more readable and easy to maintain. Obviously I can't say this with certainty, but I can't come up with a use case where iterating through all objects looking for the data frames is superior to keeping your data frames in a list and then calling each item in that list.

Comment: Thanks a ton JD! This is exactly what I was looking for!! -rb

Answer (score 12):

You can get an object from its name with get or mget and iterate with one of the apply type functions. For example,

```
sapply(mget(ls(), .GlobalEnv), is.data.frame)
```

will tell you which items in the global environment are data frames. To use within a function, you can specify an environment to the ls call.

Answer (score 8):

You can loop through objects in environment using "eapply".

Answer (score 3):

Throwing in another solution to the mix using `inherits`. It basically (a) gets all objects from the current environment and (b) checks if they inherit from a data frame.

```
sapply(sapply(ls(), get), inherits, 'data.frame')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `get()` to refer to an object by name

```
# Create some objects
df <- data.frame(a=1:10)
dl <- list(a=1, b=2, c=3)

# Use `ls()` to return a list of object names
lso <- ls()

# Use `get()` to refer to specific objects
class(get(lso[1]))
[1] "data.frame"

# Using an apply function to evaluate the class
lapply(lso, function(x) class(get(x)))
[[1]]
[1] "data.frame"

[[2]]
[1] "list"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Filter` with `is.data.frame` and `ls` in `mget` to get a named list of in this case of `data.frame` objects.
This `list` can then be used e.g. in `lapply` to apply each element of the list to a function.

```
L <- Filter(is.data.frame, mget(ls()))

lapply(L, nrow)
```