# loop over dataframes in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to make a series of plots using ggplot from multiple different dataframes. I was planning on using a list and iterating over the list as follows:

```
libraries <- objects() #make a list of the dataframes we want to graph
for(i in libraries) {
  # create initial plots
  x1 <- qplot(data= i, V1, reorder(V2,V3), color = V3) + coord_flip()
  x2 <- ggplot(i, aes(x=reorder(V2,V3), group=V3, color=V3)) + geom_bar() 
  x3 <- ggplot(i, aes(x=V1, group=V3, color=V3)) + coord_flip() + geom_bar()
}
```

however I get the error message:

```
Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class factor
```

presumably because 'libraries' is now a character variable and not a data frame. Any one have another suggestion on how to iterate through the dataframes? I suppose I could merge them with plyr and then ggplot a subset of the data but that seems to add more work.

Comment: Don't make lists of character variables when you want to work with lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way to iterate over data.frames (which are just regularly organized lists) is with `lapply`:

```
 df1 <- data.frame(date = as.Date(10*365*rbeta(100, .5, .1)),group="a")
  df2 <- data.frame(date = as.Date(10*365*rbeta(50, .1, .5)),group="b")
  df3 <- data.frame(date = as.Date(10*365*rbeta(25, 3,3)),group="c")
  dfrmL <- list(df1,df2,df3)

 lapply(dfrmL, NROW)
[[1]]
[1] 100

[[2]]
[1] 50

[[3]]
[1] 25
```

In the case of producing a list of ggplot-objects I would imagine that the Hadley-method would instead be to use `llply`, but I'm not a skilled plyr-user, so let me suggest this totally untested code template:

```
plts <- lapply(dfrmL, function(df) qplot(qplot(data= df, 
                                          V1, reorder(V2,V3), color = V3) + 
                                  coord_flip()
       )  
 # you may need to explicitly print() or plot() the plots as stated in the R-FAQ.    
lapply(plts, print)
```

Comment: thanks @DWin but what about if you want to use many dataframes? Lets say I have a 30 dataframes. I suppose I could manually write a list but the idea of using the objects() was to get the list of dataframes. Do you know of a way to get an `lapply` -able list of dataframes in your workspace?

Comment: Your workspace is an environment and there is an `eapply` function.

Comment: @Zach - check out this question for an example of identifying all objects of a given class (data.frame for example) which may be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158830/identify-all-objects-of-given-class-for-further-processing

Comment: @DWin I think joran has a good way of getting a useable list of datasets and I will try to iterate through them as you suggest. thanks

Answer (score 3):

A more complete, reproducible example may help us suggest a *better* way to accomplish this, but at the very least I can suggest replacing:

```
libraries <- objects()
```

with this

```
libraries <- lapply(objects(), FUN = get)
```

which will actually build a list of all the objects in the current environment. But I somehow doubt that the data frames are the *only* objects in your environment, so perhaps you would rather grab the list of objects using `objects` or `ls`, use `grep` (or a related function) to find only your data frames based on their names and then `get` just those data frames using `lapply`.

Finally, you can then iterate over them as @Dwin describes.

Comment: thanks joran. I am going for something like this: `df1 <- diamonds[1:100,]
df2 <- diamonds[101:200,]

libraries <- lapply(objects(), FUN = get) #make a list of the dataframes we want to graph
plts <- lapply(libraries, function(df) qplot(qplot(data= df, x,y, color = clarity)) )

lapply(plts, funtion(pic) print(pic) png(file=pic.jpg) dev(off) )`

Comment: try `ggsave` instead of `png+dev.off` (you'd need `print()` in the middle, btw).