# R sub-setting the list of objects in the global environment by class

Tags: r, class, list, subset

I would like to be able to subset the list of objects in my Global Environment by class.

i.e. from the list created by running

ls()

I would like to be able to make a shorter list that only has the names of the objects that belong to specific class e.g. xts or POSIXlt

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158830/identify-all-objects-of-given-class-for-further-processing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could retrieve `ls()` and check the class of everything. It may not be particularly efficient though, as it does the filtering *after* `ls()` and not within.

```
# populate global environment with some vars.
rm(list=ls())
a <- 1
b <- 2
c <- 'foo'
d <- 'asdf'
lst <- ls()
# return everything 'numeric':
lst[sapply(lst,function(var) any(class(get(var))=='numeric'))]
# 'a' 'b'
```

The `get(var)` gets the variable corresponding to the string in `var`, so if `var` is `"a"` then `get(var)` retrieves 1 (being the value of variable `a`).

As @VincentZoonekynd notes below - it is possible for objects to have multiple classes. Soo `class(some_xts_object)` is `c("xts","zoo")` -- the above method will return `some_xts_object` if you search for `xts` objects, but *also* if you search for `zoo` objects.

Comment: That assumes that objects belong to only one class. This is not always the case: for instance, `xts` objects are also of class `zoo`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realise you could have multiple classes. I'll add an `any(class(..)=='numeric')` (`class(some_xts_object)` gives c('xts','zoo'); may this be relied upon?)

Comment: `class(some_xts_object)` will always contain at least `xts` and `zoo`, but could contain more. I usually use `"xts" %in% class(u)`, which is equivalent to your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

This is a slight twist to the above which uses `inherits` to inspect the object:

```
objs =  mget(ls(envir=.GlobalEnv), envir=.GlobalEnv)
names(Filter(function(i) inherits(i, "lm"), objs))
```

The function(i) inherits(i, "lm") can be adjusted as you want.

Comment: +1 for use of `mget`, which in this instance, does *not* increase memory usage appreciably.