# Only list objects in class data.frame

Tags: r, class, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Identify all objects of given class for further processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158830/identify-all-objects-of-given-class-for-further-processing)

I want to build an index of every data frame I have in my workspace. How do I write something sounding like:

```
dindex <- ls(class=data.frame)
```

Comment: have you seen [`.ls.objects`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358003/tricks-to-manage-the-available-memory-in-an-r-session)?

Comment: this question is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158830/identify-all-objects-of-given-class-for-further-processing

Comment: Actually, I need more help here. .ls.objects lists modes, but does not restrict results to a 'mode' argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the link @Chase provided in the comments, you can `Filter` the results of `ls` to only include the names of objects that `inherit` the `data.frame` class.

```
#R --vanilla -q
a <- data.frame(1:3)
b <- data.frame(1:2, 4:3)
L <- list(a, b)
Filter(function(x) inherits(get(x), "data.frame"), ls())
#[1] "a" "b"
```

Comment: Great and useful answer!