# How to write a is.customClass function in R?

Tags: r, object

We all know functions like `is.data.frame` or `is.double` etc. Probably easy to do but hard to google: How can create your own is.? function? Is there a better way to do it then:

```
is.myClass <- function(x){
if(class(x) %in% "myClass") return(TRUE)
else return(FALSE)
}
```

Comment: This question seems related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158830/identify-all-objects-of-given-class-for-further-processing

Comment: I think that should go the other way around: `function(x) {"myClass" %in% class(x)}`, but as @James points out `inherits` is more idiomatic (I don't know whether it has any other advantages)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps `inherits` is enough:

```
is.myClass <- function(x) {inherits(x,"myClass")}

x <- 1
is.myClass(x)
[1] FALSE
class(x) <- c(class(x),"myClass")
is.myClass(x)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: You don't need `{` and `}` for single line functions

Comment: @hadley force of habit. Can't remember if the intepreter imposes a penalty for using them.

Comment: remembering whether or not there is a interpreter penalty is a waste of time; it just looks ugly to my eyes